# Failed to find DRM Plugin

Tags: android, genymotion, android-drm

I'm trying to run my app with Gmail Login on genymotion emulator. But I keep getting a Failed to find DRM plugin error. I have added the ARM translation zip to the emulator and gApps for the given device. The app runs perfectly on real devices(HTC desire 500 and a Nexus 5). The emulator is a Nexus 5 with Lollipop 5.1.

```
02-20 05:27:13.292 1693-2186/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
02-20 05:27:13.292 3684-3868/? W/DG.WV: Widevine DRM not supported on this device
02-20 05:27:13.292 3684-3868/? W/DG.WV: android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object.
02-20 05:27:13.292 3684-3868/? W/DG.WV:     at android.media.MediaDrm.native_setup(Native Method)
02-20 05:27:13.292 3684-3868/? W/DG.WV:     at android.media.MediaDrm.<init>(MediaDrm.java:180)
02-20 05:27:13.292 3684-3868/? W/DG.WV:     at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.q.run(SourceFile:99)
02-20 05:27:13.292 3684-3868/? W/DG.WV:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-20 05:27:13.292 3684-3868/? W/DG.WV:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-20 05:27:13.292 3684-3868/? W/DG.WV:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-20 05:27:13.300 2686-3863/? V/BaseAuthAsyncOperation: access token request successful
02-20 05:27:13.301 3684-3735/? I/GoogleURLConnFactory: Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
02-20 05:27:13.742 3471-3471/? I/adfjksf: Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
02-20 05:27:13.814 3471-3492/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 05:27:13.814 3471-3492/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3ee7840, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 05:27:14.837 2279-3867/? W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key:
```

Comment: have you find any solution ?
I am facing same issue.

Comment: Hello guys. I am having the same problem. Why is this happening?

Comment: Most of the emulators does not support drm

Answer (score 4):

DRM is not supported in emulators as the hardware is not capable of that . You can check the availability of drm by installing Drm info application and run it in the emulator. Please find the link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidfung.drminfo